# Javascript window.open url with spaces and %

Tags: javascript, escaping, spaces, window.open

I'm trying `window.open` with a url with spaces:

```
var msg = 'Hello, world!';  
var url = 'http://yoursite.com';  
var link = 'http://www.twitter.com/share?text=' + msg + '&url=' + url; 
window.open(link);
```

Running this code will open a new window with `http://twitter.com/share?text=Hello,%2520world!&url=http://yoursite.com`.

What happens is that the space in msg is converted to %20, then the '%' is converted to %25.  As a workaround, i added:

`msg = msg.replace(/\s/g, '+');`

But are there other chars i need to watch out for or is there a better workaround?

Comment: i forgot to add that i'm using Drupal with jQuery.  This code is wrapped within a Drupal.behaviors...not that i think these affect anything.

Answer (score 15):

Try this instead:

```
var msg = encodeURIComponent('Hello, world!');  
var url = encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com');  
var link = 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + msg + '&url=' + url; 
window.open(link);
```

Note the different Twitter url and the encoding of the query string params.

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode URLs.

There cannot be any spaces in the URL.

Therefore the browser reinterprets the url spaces as it wants unless you tell it exactly how:

```
var msg = 'Hello,%20world!';
```

Comment: idk. dont use spaces in your URL

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that if you use the url `http://www.twitter.com` your msg gets escaped twice. If you look at [twitters dev page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents), they use `https://twitter.com`.

For your code, remove the **www** and I think it's good to use **https** instead of **http**

```
var msg = 'Hello, world!';  
var url = 'http://yoursite.com';  
var link = 'https://twitter.com/share?text=' + msg + '&url=' + url; 
window.open(link);
```

You don't even need to use encodeURI or escape on your message.